# Best Free Ordinary Differential Equation Library in .net

Tags: c#, equation, solver, ode

I'm looking for a library to solve ODE for my university thesis' project...
The library I'd like to find had to have this features:

- Event Calculus (something like a continuous calculus stopped by internal event, like constraint reached and other events)
- I'm using C# 4.0 so i think any library will be ok
- Have good performance
- No $$ ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done before is either code in something from [Numerical Recipies](http://www.nrbook.com/a) or compile a fortran dll (from [NETLIB](http://www.netlib.org/ode/index.html) for example) and call it using `[DllImport()]`. Doing a call back is kind of a hasle, but I figured it out using the examples from [NAG](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/csharpinfo.asp).

Also they may offer an academic version of [NAG Library for.NET](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/?DT/DTdescription.asp)

Comment: Its worth reading this before considering Numerical Recipes http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/wnnr/nr.html

Answer (score 6):

Created a [dedicated ODE solving library](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/CSharpOdeLibrary) - simple to use based on C++ Boost.OdeInt core.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like people on SO like MATLAB from .NET http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/

Also, [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/).

Sources:

- [Solving partial differential equations using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452255/solving-partial-differential-equations-using-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net